# How do I check is a postgresql procedure exists before calling it

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a procedure that may not exist in the schema ( it self installs when a service starts )

I'm currently calling it from within another procedure with

`perform some_schema.some_job(x)`

How do I check that this procedure exists before I call it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could run

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc
               WHERE proname = 'some_job'
                 AND pronamespace = 'some_schema'::regnamespace)
THEN
   ...
END IF;
```

But that is a bad idea, because there is a race condition.
What if a concurrent session runs the same code and creates the function between your check and the call to the function?

Normally it is better to do something like:

```
BEGIN
   /* might fail if the function does not exist */
   PERFORM some_schema.some_job(x);
EXCEPTION
   WHEN undefined_function THEN
      BEGIN
         CREATE FUNCTION ...
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN duplicate_function THEN
            /* this is ok, concurrent process created it */
            NULL;
      END;

      /* now it cannot fail */
      PERFORM some_schema.some_job(x);
END;
```